# Wie sende ich eine "freundliche Erinnerung" an jemanden bei der Arbeit, wenn ich auf meine Fragen keine Antwort erhalte?

Tags: translation

Ich habe einer Arbeitskollegin 3-4 Fragen gestellt. Aber ich habe seit 3 Tagen keine Antwort von ihr erhalten und möchte sie freundlich an dieses Thema erinnern. Wie soll ich ihr dafür eine E-Mail schicken?

Comment: Möchtest Du jetzt eine freundliche Erinnerung senden, oder eine "freundliche Erinnerung"? Mit Anführungszeichen würde ich es ironisch interpretieren, also eine nur scheinbar freundliche Erinnerung. Text und Überschrift gehen da aber auseinander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es kommt durchaus auf das jeweilige Verhältnis untereinander an. Eine relativ wenig vorwurfsvolle Variante ist

> Hattest Du schon einmal Zeit, Dir meine Fragen vom Freitag anzugucken?

> Konntest Du Dir über meine Fragen vom Freitag schon etwas Gedanken machen?

Natürlich lässt sich das ganze auch mit 'Sie' formulieren, wenn ihr nicht per Du seid.

Man kann dem Ganzen etwas mehr Nachdruck oder Dringlichkeit verleihen indem man nach einer Zeitspanne bzw. einem Antwortzeitpunkt fragt:

> Was meinen Sie bis wann Sie mir Rückmeldung zu meinen Fragen vom vergangenen Donnerstag geben können?

Ob per E-Mail oder Telefon oder persönlich kommt auch auf die Umstände an... persönlich oder zumindest im Gespräch lässt sich nicht so leicht entkommen und wegklicken und dürfte deshalb nachhaltiger sein.

Comment: Das "einmal" klingt da ein bisschen komisch für mich und würde ich so nicht schreiben.

Comment: @idmean stimmt. Schreiben würde ich es in eine E-Mail ohne das 'einmal'. Aber sagen würde ich es genau so.

Comment: Eventuell ist das regional unterschiedlich (?), aber für mich (Südwestdeutschland) klingt "_sich_ über etwas nachdenken" ziemlich merkwürdig. Entweder "über etwas nachdenken" oder "sich über etwas Gedanken machen".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ja, danke. Das ist mindestens schief (gewesen) Zu schnell getippt. Entweder "über etwas nachdenken" oder "sich über etwas Gedanken machen".

Comment: danke für Ihre Hilfe!